# Can't update global variables from promise in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I'm new to Nodejs, and I've been writing a Web3 handler for my contract, everything works good but the global variables don't update during the promise execution, they have no value even when I console.log after the Then.

```
...
var cityDb = {};
function gettingBalance() {

    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => { 

        Contract.totalSupply.call(function(error, result){
            if(!error)
                {

                resolve(result.toNumber());
                }
            else

                reject(error);
        });
    });
}


function gettingCities(cityNumber) {

    return new Promise ( (resolve,reject) => { 

        Contract.CityDB.call( cityNumber, (error, result) => {
            if(!error)
                {

                    resolve(result);

                }
            else
                reject(error);
        });

    });

}



gettingBalance()
    .then ( (result) => {
        console.log('Total after function: '+result);
        return result;
    })
        .then ( (totalSupply) => {
            console.log('loop data :'+totalSupply);

            // START SECOND PROMISE 

            for (let i=0; i <= totalSupply; i++) { 

                gettingCities(i) 
                    .then( (result) => {

                    cityDb[i] = {
                            cityName: result[0],
                            Population: result[1],
                            };


                        let j = i-1;
                        console.log('Loop ['+i+']'+ cityDb[i].cityName);

                    })
                    .catch( (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

                    if (i == totalSupply) { return;  }

            }


            // END SECOND PROMISE

        })
        .then ( (response) => {
            console.log('Test promise loop: '+ cityDb[2]);
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log('loop error: '+err);
        });
```

Log results :

```
Total supply after function: 3
loop data :3
Test promise loop: undefined
Loop [0]0x4e657720596f726b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Loop [1]0x5061726973000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Loop [2]0x4e61646f72000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Loop [3]0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why is test promise loop undefined? The cityDB isn't getting update from the loop, but the loop works perfectly as intended.

Comment: I fixed my problem by using async / await....  I'm still curious as to why variables are not being assigned, when they are used inside "then", so I'd be grateful for any answer

Comment: check my answer, and let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you weren't chaining promises correctly. Your last `then` wasn't waiting until all your `gettingCities` calls were done. For that you can use `Promise.all`

```
gettingBalance()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('Total after function: ' + result);
        return result;
    })
    .then((totalSupply) => {
        console.log('loop data :' + totalSupply);

        // START SECOND PROMISE 
        const promises = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
            // We push gettingCities promises into the array
            promises.push(gettingCities(i));    
        }

        // We pass gettingCities promises into Promise.all
        return Promise.all(promises);

    })
    .then((results) => {

        // All gettingCities results
        // We loop through each result and fill cityDb
        results.forEach((result, i) => {

            cityDb[i] = {
                cityName: result[0],
                Population: result[1],
            };

            console.log('Loop [' + i + ']' + cityDb[i].cityName);
        })

        console.log('Test promise loop: ' + cityDb[2]);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('loop error: ' + err);
    });
```

You can remove the global `cityDb` and just handle it in the last `.then`

```
.then((results) => {

    // gettingCities results
    const cityDb = {};
    results.forEach((result, i) => {

        cityDb[i] = {
            cityName: result[0],
            Population: result[1],
        };

        console.log('Loop [' + i + ']' + cityDb[i].cityName);
    })

    console.log('Test promise loop: ' + cityDb[2]);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  so Promise.all() was what I needed... It's still not perfectly clear, I'll have to try it out. You can only pass promises inside Promise.all, but you passed in an object. Also it seems you used push on an object, does it work ? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. `Promise.all` takes an `array` of promises and I passed an array, have in mind that `[]` is an array, an object literal is `{}`.

Comment: No problem, we were all new sometime :)! glad to help.